# Makefile: missing separator. Stop

Tags: makefile

I am trying to make a simple c++ project using vim only. And I saw this simple project structure and I would like to use it. It has bin build doc include lib makefile spike src test. But when I try to use `make` it says

```
makefile:19 *** missing separator. Stop.
```

this is my code on my makefile

```
# TODO: Move `libmongoclient.a` to /usr/local/lib so this can work on production servers
#

CC := g++ # This is the main compiler
# CC := clang --analyze # and comment out the linker last line for sanity
SRCDIR := src
BUILDDIR := build
TARGET := bin/runner

SRCEXT := cpp
SOURCES := $(shell find $(SRCDIR) -type f -name *.$(SRCEXT))
OBJECTS := $(patsubst $(SRCDIR)/%,$(BUILDDIR)/%,$(SOURCES:.$(SRCEXT)=.o))
CFLAGS := -g # -Wall
LIB := -pthread -lmongoclient -L lib -lboost_thread-mt -lboost_filesystem-mt -lboost_system-mt
INC := -I include

$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
  @echo " Linking...";
  @echo " $(CC) $^ -o $(TARGET) $(LIB)"; $(CC) $^ -o $(TARGET) $(LIB)

$(BUILDDIR)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.$(SRCEXT)
  @mkdir -p $(BUILDDIR)
  @echo " $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INC) -c -o $@ $<"; $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INC) -c -o $@ $<

clean:
  @echo " Cleaning..."; 
  @echo " $(RM) -r $(BUILDDIR) $(TARGET)"; $(RM) -r $(BUILDDIR) $(TARGET)

# Tests
tester:
  $(CC) $(CFLAGS) test/tester.cpp $(INC) $(LIB) -o bin/tester

# Spikes
ticket:
  $(CC) $(CFLAGS) spikes/ticket.cpp $(INC) $(LIB) -o bin/ticket

.PHONY: clean
```

Comment: tried it without the  ; it still doesnt work

Comment: Actions after the rule need a preceding TAB character.

Comment: ok thanks it works now!

Comment: This question is not really related to vim anyhow.